# Returning list of search values that were not updated (Mongoose, updateMany)

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, express, mongoose

Using Mongoose's `updateMany` function, I'm able to provide a search list to find users and update accordingly.

```
const searchList = ["userA", "userB", "UNKNOWNUSER"];
const updatedRecords = await User.updateMany({username: {$in: searchList}}, {foo: "bar"});
```

The number of results can easily be found with `nmodified`. But if there is a user that could not be found, obviously in that case it won't be updated. Not entirely sure how to find the elements in searchList that could not be found or updated in the one-round Mongoose trip other than some ugly `BulkWrite` or synchronous loop functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this answer is not about the bulk insertion that you asked but it might help. you can use for loop here if you want to get the data to existing for insertion:

```
const searchList = ["userA", "userB", "UNKNOWNUSER"];
for(user of searchList){
   const updated = await User.findOneAndUpdate({username: user}, {$set:{foo: "bar"}}, {new : true});
   if(updated){
     // that means it would be found
   }

}
```

Comment: Let's say for instance I bulk select 100 users or 1000 users.. would this significantly affect the return time or performance since it's continually requesting that many times?

Comment: @trafalgarson ofc this is not efficient. but when we say bulk insertion into the DB I don't think you can have such controls like that.